Insert Google Merchant Center bulk_price data into JSON-LD structured product markup?
The product Offer schema uses elegibleQuantity to specify volume pricing (quantity breaks).
Google wants the information using bulk_price within customAttributes instead.
Since the schema doesn't even mention support for those 2 keywords, is there a way to include the data for Google inside the offer schema, in a way that the schema passes validation and Google finds and interprets the data?
I'd like to find a way to have the bulk-price embedded into the product page (that already has Product and Offer structured data) instead of having to upload it to GMC manually.
